# Error with message_to_tf, in ros fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with message_to_tf.the problem is when you compile message_to_tf.
when rosmake is used gives the following error:

error: /home/dava/local/src/ros-fuerte/hector_common/message_to_tf/src/message_to_tf.cpp:40:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘btMatrix3x3::btMatrix3x3(tf::Quaternion&)’

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47906/error-with-message_to_tf,-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the fuerte branch of the [hector_common](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_common) stack or [message_to_tf](http://ros.org/wiki/message_to_tf) where `btMatrix3x3` and other bullet types have been replaced by the respective tf types. The URL of the repository is https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_common.

See http://ros.org/wiki/hector_common for further details.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2012-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2012-12-26**:
In the meantime, the fuerte branch has been merged with the trunk branch and /trunk/hector_common can be used for ROS electric and upwards.